# How to make client approve a server certificate?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, python-requests, flask-restful

I need to make client approve a server CA certificate which is not known to it.

I have generated `cert.pem` using the following command

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365
```

And then using the following command I came to know that `requests` points to `<full-path>/cacert.pem`.

```
python -mrequests.certs
```

So, I have copied the generated `cert.pem` to the same path and gave it to `verify`. I have tried the following to do so. I don't want to use `verify=False`.

```
requests.get("https://<ip>:<port>/route1", verify='<full-path>/cert.pem')
```

Still I see that the client is throwing the following error.

> SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

How do I make the client approve the server certificate? Am I missing anything? Any help would be appreciated.

**Server side code**

```
context = ('cert.pem', 'key.pem')
#app is flask object
app.run(host="<ip>", port=port, debug=Ture, ssl_context=context)
```